# Link Duplicity problem with .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry I couldn't come up with a better title.

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

And this is my problem:

localhost/validpage gives me the contents of localhost/validpage.php.
localhost/validpage/blah also gives me the same (validpage.php) page and so does localhost/validpage/blah/blah/...
Therefore the problem I am facing is link *duplicity*(in my words!).

How do I allow  `localhost/validpage.php` to be accessed from `localhost/validpage` only and nothing else, not even `localhost/validpage.php`.

I have started a question on [*Server****Fault***](https://serverfault.com/questions/185725/link-duplicity-and-mod-rewrite) too but with not much success.
The answer I have got is it cannot be done with htaccess alone.

By validpage I mean any *valid* page on the server. Since I am retrofitting an existing site with mod_rewrite for cleaner urls, I am looking for a relatively easy solution preferably with .htaccess only. However, any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the source attribute of your images, etc ???
absolute or relative?

`<img src="/images/my.jpg" />` and `<img src="images/my.jpg" />` point to different files when applying your rewrite rules.

Comment: i can get around the problem by doing this. but I wanted to know why do I not get a 404

Comment: if the answer doesn't make sense, it is because I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if request has a php extension remove and redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^((.*)\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1 [L,R=301]

# if request uri has no extension link to php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I should rewrite your php scripts to friendly urls, and redirect requests using the .php extension.